# Python Google Analytics Active users list

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have a lot of potential users for my website (not open to the public).

I do have a Google Analytics account and everything is working well.

I don't want to iterate through all potential users because calling for each individual user will take a very long time (I have about 1200 users).

Instead, I want a list of only active users in the given time period.

Surely this must be possible

(Simple problem, I am happy to answer any questions as I know this is a very brief question I am asking)

EDITED:

I am working in python and need to write code to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a list of user ids that you can use with the user activity API, the analytics API has a dimension called 'ga:clientId' that you can call and then filter using the standard parameters - there's a list of options of what you can filter on here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportrequest

Depending on how you are describing 'active users', below is an example calling the REST API from python:

```py
import requests
import json

credentials = #{ 'your credentials as a dict' }

r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", data = {
        "client_id": credentials["client_id"],
        "client_secret": credentials["client_secret"],
        "refresh_token": credentials["refresh_token"],
        "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        }
     )

access_token =json.loads(r.text)

body = {
    "reportRequests": [
        {
            'viewId': # "your ga view ID",
            'pageSize': 100000,
            "includeEmptyRows": True,
            "samplingLevel": "LARGE",
            'dateRanges': [
                {
                    'startDate': "7DaysAgo",
                    'endDate': "yesterday"
                }
            ],
            'metrics': [
                {
                   'expression': "ga:sessions"
                }
            ],
            'filtersExpression': "ga:sessions>2",
            'dimensions': [
                {
                    'name': "ga:clientId"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

resp = requests.post("https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet",
                         json=body,
                         headers = {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + access_token["access_token"]}
                        )

resp = resp.json()


print(json.dumps(resp, indent = 4))


clientIds = [ x["dimensions"][0] for x in resp["reports"][0]["data"]["rows"]  ]

print(clientIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer above, you need to use a combination of the above plus the useractivity.list method.

I have written a full blog post on it https://medium.com/@alrowe/how-to-pull-out-the-user-explorer-report-with-python-useractivity-search-369bc5052093

Once you have used the above to get a list of client ids, you then need to iterate through those.

My 2 api calls look like this:

```
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body = {
         "reportRequests": [
             {
                'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                'pageSize': 100000,
                'includeEmptyRows': True,
                'samplingLevel': 'LARGE',
                'dateRanges': [
                   {
                       'startDate': '30DaysAgo',
                       'endDate': 'yesterday'
                   }
                ],
                'metrics': [
                   {
                      'expression': 'ga:sessions'
                   }
                ],
                'filtersExpression': 'ga:sessions>2',
                'dimensions': [
                   {
                      'name': "ga:clientId"
                   }
                ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ).execute()
```

and then

```
def get_client_list_report(analytics,client_id):
   return analytics.userActivity().search(
      body = {
         'user': {
            'type': 'CLIENT_ID',
            'userId': client_id
         },
         'dateRange':
         {
            'startDate': '30DaysAgo',
            'endDate': 'yesterday'
         },
         'viewId': VIEW_ID,
         'pageSize': 100000,
      }
).execute()
```